# Refresh HTML Document via Javascript in a GAS Embedded Environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, reload, document-body

So I've created a simple time-keeping app in Google Appscript to store data in spreadsheets and display the information in an embedded Javascript/JQuery applet on the internal Google Site. It looks like this:

[image: Snapshot of program]

My problem is that some users leave the browser page open for too long and have to click the object twice in order to log out or log in, or refresh the page. I was hoping to set an interval timer to do the refresh for them to save them a step. Below is my code on the front end to process an interval refresh and recreate the body HTML after a set amount of idle time:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://...moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://...moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://...moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<script>
// When the page loads.
function start(){
 try{var dateString = moment(new Date()).format('L');}
 catch(e){var dateString = getNowDateString();}
 document.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("clock").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("interface").style.display = "none";
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showTimeTrack).pullCard(JSON.stringify({email:DATA.email, date:dateString, source:'TimeTrack'}));
}
function showTimeTrack(payload) {
console.log(payload);
var body = $('body').clone();
var time = new Date().getTime();
var data = JSON.parse(payload);
var greenflag = (data.greenflag) ? true: false;
var interface = document.getElementById('interface');
var emailDiv = document.createElement('small');
emailDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Connected as: '));
emailDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
emailDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(DATA.email));
emailDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
emailDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
interface.appendChild(emailDiv);

var lastLogDiv = document.createElement('small');
lastLogDiv.innerHTML = '<b>'+data.timecard.info.message+'</b>';
lastLogDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
if(data.timecard.info.lastRole.length > 0)
{
  lastLogDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('As: '+data.timecard.info.lastRole));
}
interface.appendChild(lastLogDiv);

//...Creating various HTML Elements...

interface.appendChild(logBtn); 
interface.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); 
interface.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

var cardButton = document.createElement('button');
cardButton.innerHTML = 'View Timecard';
console.log(DATA);
cardButton.onclick = function(){openWindowWithPost(JSON.stringify({timecard: data.timecard, directory: DATA.DIRECTORY}));}
interface.appendChild(cardButton);
interface.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
interface.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

 setClock();
 document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("title").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("clock").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("interface").style.display = "block";
 
 var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
    $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
       time = new Date().getTime();console.log(time);});
    console.log('Current run is at '+moment(time).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
   if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 10000) 
      {
        var body = $('body').clone(); document.body.innerHTML = ''; $('body').html(body); start(); var body = $('body').clone(); 
        time = new Date().getTime(); 
        console.log('refreshed at '+moment(new Date()).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
      }
  else {
         console.log('checked at '+moment(new Date()).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
        }}, 3000);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTION SETCLOCK////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function setClock()
{
  var now = moment(new Date()).tz(DATA.timeZone).format('hh:mm:ss A z');
  $('#time').html(now);
   setTimeout('setClock()',500);
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var DATA = <?!= JSON.stringify(dataFromServerTemplate) ?>;
</script>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CSS').getContent(); ?>
</head>
<body onload="start()">

<div id = "loader" class="heart-rate">
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 125 73" enable-background="new 0 0 150 73">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CE0000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,45.486 38.514,45.486 44.595,33.324 50.676,45.486 57.771,45.486 62.838,55.622 71.959,9 80.067,63.729 84.122,45.486 97.297,45.486 103.379,40.419 110.473,45.486 150,45.486"
    />
  </svg>
  <div class="fade-in"></div>
  <div class="fade-out"></div>
</div>

<p  id = 'title' style="font-size:18px; text-align: center; display: none;"><b>Time<font color="#ff0000">Track</font></b></p>
<div id="clock" style = "display: none;"><small>Current Time:<div id = 'time'></div></small></div><br>
<div id="interface" tex-align: center;></div>  
<div id = 'modal' class = 'modal'>
<div id = 'modalContent' class = 'modal-content'>
</div></div>
<span id = 'closeModal' class = 'close'></span>
<form id="timeCardPost" method="post" action="MustSetURL" target="TheWindow">
<input type="hidden" name="payload" value="set card JSON here" />
</form>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JS-TimeTrack').getContent();?>
</body>
</html>
```

unfortunately, after the first refresh, the interval seems to reload the page and then add another copy of the body under it ad infinitum, like in the screenshot below:

[image: Constant appendages!]

I've tried location.reload(with true and false statements). That just results in a white screen. I've tried setting the HTML body to (), but that seems to work the same way. Would anyone know how to reset the body tag of the page instead of just concatenating?

Thanks,
        Nathaniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery `clone()` method makes a copy of the selected element.  What you are ending up with is `body` tags inside of other body tags, each one nested inside of the other.

### Currently

```
var body = $('body').clone();
document.body.innerHTML = ''; 
$('body').html(body); 
start(); 
var body = $('body').clone();
```

### Try

```
var body = document.body.innerHTML;//Get the HTML inside of the `body` tag
document.body.innerHTML = '';//Clear the existing HTML from the `body` tag

console.log('body: ' + body);

document.body.innerHTML = body;

start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sandy. I figured there was some sort of nesting behavior going too. Unfortunately, I copied your line of code, and it does the same thing. I wonder if, in a Google Apps Script environment, maybe the embedded nature of the script means the body tag can never be empty? I hope not. I'll try to reset each element individually instead of trying to clone the whole body in one line.

Comment: Being an Apps Script Web App shouldn't make any difference.  You should do some debugging with `console.log('body: ' + body)`  I made a change to the answer.

Comment: Problem Resolved. I ended up using this code to handle the individual elements instead of trying to clone the body.
       document.getElementById('time').innerHTML='';
       document.getElementById('interface').innerHTML='';
       document.getElementById('modalContent').innerHTML='';
       document.getElementById('closeModal').innerHTML='';
       start();                                                                                                             Thank you Sandy for pointing me in the right direction!